# Detecting empty rows in associated table and print out dummy data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables with a one-to-many relationship. Table A has columns

```
- id
- Name
```

Table B is associated with Table A. Table B belongs to Table A. Table B has columns

```
- id
- TableA_id_ForeignKey
- TimeChange
- Status
```

I want to write a MySQL query such that when Table B has no associated row entries for Table A, dummy data will be printed in the output for that particular row in Table A. The result will be something like;

```
TableA_Name 0000-00-00  00
```

One will be able to tell which row in Table A has no associated rows  with some dummy data. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
b.*,
coalesce(a.name, '0000-00-00 00') as dummy
from
b
left join a on b.a_fk = a.id
```

With this `left join` you get all rows from `b`, regardless if there's a matching row in `a`. If there's no matching row, `null` is returned. Then the `coalesce()` function returns the first of its parameters which isn't `null`.

UPDATE: Understood the question wrong...

```
select
a.*,
'hello' as dummy /*with the where clause you just get rows where there's no match anyway*//
from
b
right join a on b.a_fk = a.id
where b.id is null
```

Comment: Sorry, I just tested that the answer is not right. It does not return any rows if there are no matching associated rows in Table B. Also, if there's a matching row, I would like to query to not return any rows. Thank you.

Comment: @user3293156 Edited my answer. A good way to avoid confusion is to always attach sample data and desired result to a question.

Comment: Thank you very much. The answer is right now. Wished I could upvote your answer 10 times.

Comment: Well, tell your friends, spread the word ;) Just kidding, glad I could help.